# Is there an optimal way of synchronizing access to a Map between 2 threads (1 reader - 1 writer)

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following two datastructures:

```
// Session -> Symbol -> ID
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> mapping1;
// Symbol -> ID -> Level -> Value
Map<String, Map<Long, Map<Integer, Double>>> mapping2;
```

and the following methods:

```
void addSession(String session, String symbol, Long id) {
    mapping1.computeIfAbsent(session, k -> new HashMap<>())
        .put(symbol, id);
}

void removeSession(String session, String symbol, Long id); // similar to above

void addValue(String symbol, Long id, Integer level, Double value) {
    mapping2.computeIfAbsent(symbol, k -> new HashMap<>())
        .computeIfAbsent(id, k -> new HashMap<>())
            .put(level, value);
}

Double getValue(String session, String symbol, Integer level) {
    int id = mapping1.get(session).get(symbol);
    return mapping2.get(symbol).get(id).get(level);
}
```

Now the issue is, we have 1 thread that is doing all the writing (add/removeSession and addValue), and 1 thread that is doing all the reading (getValue). The writes heavily outweigh the reads.

Expected call count:

- add/removeSession - a few times a day
- addValue - ~100 a second
- getValue - every few seconds

Given this, I'm wondering what would be the best way to synchronise these 2 threads without using a lock? I'm trying to figure out a way of flattening all the data into a single map but can't seem to think of anything.

EDIT: to make clear. We want to synchronize access to the Value in mapping2. This can be updated 100s of times in a second.

Comment: @kerberos84 visibility?

Comment: @kerberos84 edited to make clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Threads accessing the same data, it doesn't matter how often a day it happens. Either you can ensure 100% that they **never** read/write at the same time, or you can't. There's nothing inbetween.

The simplest solution would be to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Yeah, it will hurt performance, but does it really matter in your application? Try and benchmark. In most cases it doesn't matter.

Comment: this is used in the hot path of a trading application so performance is critical.

Comment: But still: "critical" doesn't mean that you have a bottleneck. Another way could be to partition your data: Don't use one `Map` for all the data, but split into multiple `Map`s. For example create a separate `Map` for each *first letter of `Symbol`* (= partition key). This of course depends on your data, if you can partition it at all or if there's any good partition key to distribute the load.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to make the methods `synchronized`. 100 times a second is a rather low rate that doesn’t require sophisticated approaches, the OP is not familiar with. In fact, with this low likelihood of contention, there’s most probably no noticeable performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

1. use the classes in the java.util.concurrent package.  Specifically ConcurrentHashMap. It will have internal locks for data integrity.
2. Add synchronize blocks to getValue() and addValue() keyed to mapping2.

or

3. You can try using the volatile keyword on the member variables.

Comment: Is your suggestion (3) to make the _mapping1_ and _mapping2_ variables **volatile**? In that case, it does not help. The **volatile** keyword makes sure the _reference_ to the map comes from main memory. That's it. It does not make any other guarantees, so if your map's `computeIfAbsent` is not thread safe, **volatile** does not magically make it thread-safe.